# What is the idiomatic scala way to add more details to the thrown exceptions wrapped in Try instances

Tags: scala, exception, idioms

For example

```
def shouldThrow:String = throw new RuntimeException("exception1")
def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String):Try[String] = {
     val ex = Try{shouldThrow}
      if(ex.isFailure)
          Failure(new RuntimeException(s"Error in context: $detail",ex.failed.get))
      else
         ex
}
shouldThrowButWithContextDetails("detail1")
//should throw new RuntimeException(s"Error in context: detail1",and the cause))
```

Does it makes sense to do such a thing in scala?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than encoding everything in an `Exception` with `Try`, it's better to use `Either` (and, better still, Scalaz `\/`), and then you can have other things than exceptions on the left hand (failure) side. You can use `scala.util.control.Exception` to capture exceptions in `Either`s:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String)
  : Either[(Exception, String), String] = {
  val ex: Either[Exception, String] = allCatch either shouldThrow
  ex.left.map { failure => (failure, s"Error in context: $detail") }
}
```

Then the `Left` (failure) case has an appropriate type `(Execption, String)` that you can handle in an appropriate way, rather than trying to smuggle the extra data in an `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that I found till now is this approach

```
def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String):Try[String] =
  Try{shouldThrow}.transform(
    x=>Success(x),
    f=>Failure(new RuntimeException(s"Error in context: $detail",f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it good to use recoverWith?

```
def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String):Try[String] = 
    Try{shouldThrow}.recoverWith{
        case ex:Throable=> Failure(new RuntimeException(s"Error in context: $detail",ex))}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal to wrap up context information like that.

However, if the intention is that the exception should ultimately be thrown you don't need to hold on to the try. It is much simpler to use **match** to separate out the failures from the successes. This is the most common way I see it used:

```
def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String): String = {
    Try {shouldThrow} match {
        case Success(s) => s
        case Failure(e) =>
          throw new RuntimeException(s"Error in context: $detail", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I realize that I was hoping to find a method like def tryInContext(context: =>Any)(block: => tryBlock):Try[T] = ???

Comment: How would you use that? What would it do that Try or try couldn't?

Comment: I would use it like `def shouldThrowButWithContextDetails(detail:String):Try[String] = tryInContext(detail)(shouldThrow)`. Try and try can do whatever is necessary. I was searching for an idiomatic way to do this.